# Android dalvik virtual machine

Tags: android, process, dalvik

i was wondering, is there a way in android OS to start a new Dalvik virtual machine, which doesn't forked from the main zygote process (the zygote virtual machine), either through adb shell, ndk or java ?

does anyone tried to use successfully in one of the adb commands: app_process, dalvikvm, dvz ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: hey can you post the syntax and explanation for how you were able to start an app in a dvm in a shell? I'm looking for something similar, and this would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `dx` to convert your bytecode to dex
2. use `dalvikvm` to run it

If you need help use -help option

```
$ dalvikvm -help

dalvikvm: [options] class [argument ...]
dalvikvm: [options] -jar file.jar [argument ...]

The following standard options are recognized:
  -classpath classpath
  -Dproperty=value
  -verbose:tag  ('gc', 'jni', or 'class')
  -ea[:<package name>... |:<class name>]
  -da[:<package name>... |:<class name>]
   (-enableassertions, -disableassertions)
  -esa
  -dsa
   (-enablesystemassertions, -disablesystemassertions)
  -showversion
  -help

The following extended options are recognized:
  -Xrunjdwp:<options>
  -Xbootclasspath:bootclasspath
  -Xcheck:tag  (e.g. 'jni')
  -XmsN  (min heap, must be multiple of 1K, >= 1MB)
  -XmxN  (max heap, must be multiple of 1K, >= 2MB)
  -XssN  (stack size, >= 1KB, <= 256KB)
  -Xverify:{none,remote,all}
  -Xrs
  -Xint  (extended to accept ':portable' and ':fast')

These are unique to Dalvik:
  -Xzygote
  -Xdexopt:{none,verified,all,full}
  -Xnoquithandler
  -Xjnigreflimit:N  (must be multiple of 100, >= 200)
  -Xjniopts:{warnonly,forcecopy}
  -Xjnitrace:substring (eg NativeClass or nativeMethod)
  -Xstacktracefile:<filename>
  -Xgc:[no]precise
  -Xgc:[no]preverify
  -Xgc:[no]postverify
  -Xgc:[no]concurrent
  -Xgc:[no]verifycardtable
  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
  -X[no]genregmap
  -Xverifyopt:[no]checkmon
  -Xcheckdexsum
```

You can also compile dalvikvm for x86 and run it in your host computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. just to make sure - this way the process doesn't fork from the zygote process? meaning it will have the same initialization of the zygote process (with minor changes of course)? thanks again

Comment: The shell where you are launching it will be the parent

Comment: And to be clear, if what you want to do is create a Zygote process, then you'll need to specify the -Xzygote option. But you will also have to do a bunch of other stuff. Refer to the Android source for app_process (IIRC) for details.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, i will refer to the source code, i managed to start a new process using dvz command but the way i understand - it's a new process where i need to give all the details (app to run and so on...) but still forked from the main zygote. if anyone wants the syntax and explanation i can post it here....

Comment: It would be useful to know what do you want to achieve

Comment: i am sorry, but i signed a confidently agreement, so i can't really say much but what i already said. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Hi @dtmilano : I am trying to run an apk using following command
adb shell dalvikvm cp *.apk classname ,but its not running , i want to use xgc:[no]precise as well , can you please tell how to pass xgc option to dalvikvm command ?

Comment: In such case I guess you need `adb shell am start ...` not `dalvikvm`